# Stack Overflow Making Cause

Tags: feature-request, crowdsourcing

I would like to request for the ability to create groups to address serious limits and problems in enterprise and even open source IDE, languages, and present it to companies, news groups.

Sometimes the lack of APIs in certain areas cause developers to waste a lot of time to manage hacks or subways. For example, some peoples created a group for Adobe Flash audio API to make Adobe hear them and expand it to those limits ( http://www.make-some-noise.info), and Adobe did it.

And there are many groups like this out here. Now, with this huge developer community which deals with pros and cons of every aspect of software development there is a lot of chance to make moves with groups and making cause on what developers in industry dealing with

Comment: What???????????

Comment: Did you see facebook causes , something like that in developers community ! , in old days of internet ( newsgroups ) , we call them noise groups , where people try to make groups on serious problems and ask companies to solve it or even add what they need

Comment: This is what I *think* the OP is trying to say. It's really difficult to understand, and even then his phrasing makes it difficult to edit

Comment: sorry for my poor english , my français is damn better

Comment: I think you mean "pressure groups" to lobby vendors etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately stackoverflow is not set up to nurture, support, or even announce social and community group effort.  While this may have value to some programmers, I don't see it as something that is so needed in our profession that changing this non-social policy is worth it.

There are many ways and other places to form such groups (you mentioned facebook, there is also linkedin, and specific forums for the technologies and companies that you are concerned about).  If you feel a need to communicate with a large subsection of Stackoverflow, you can buy ads, sponsor tags, and answer questions related to the problem with the mention of a working group.